# Create shortcut in a metro style app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Problem:
I would like to have my app multiple icons on start screen, I saw such with some online camera program (I forgot the name).

**Question**:
Can a Windows 8 Store program create an own shortcut to the start page (like for itself, but with other parameters, or for other programs, etc.)? How?

What I tried so far: Googled, maybe with the bad keywords, but found nothing but how I can make icons manually, not by my Win8 app.

Language: C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature is called Secondary Tile, app can have two or more tiles when pin to start option is used.

Here you can find more about secondary tiles : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh868249%28v=win.10%29.aspx